# Install custom ROM without using CWM or TWRP on a rooted XOLO Q1000

Tags: rom-flashing

I have a rooted XOLO Q1000 device. Due to a problem when installing the stock ROM using SP Flash Tool, I am not able to see the displayed content on my screen.

I am sure my device is working fine. It just needs to install an updated version of any ROM. As nothing is displayed properly, I am not able to start CWM. Hence, I am planning to flash custom ROM without using CWM.

Is it possible to flash a custom ROM without using CWM or TWRP on a rooted XOLO Q1000?

Answer (score 0):

If your phone has an advance recovery with this option:

- Install from sdcard
- Install from extcard
- (... or other similar options)

then it is straightforward.

However, if it doesn't exist, then you have to install an advance recovery like CWM or TWRP. I'm not sure what is the problem, but I think only this way helps you to install it.